# Share 13.10 & win 8 cpu's on home network?

Tags: networking, windows-8

I have a home network that shares folders between two win 8 systems. I can not get a connection between win systems and my Ubuntu 13.10 system but the win systems connect to each other. This is a wireless network. Suggestions on what to look for?

---11/15 Tried new workgroup, I can see the win pc now but it will not connect (details below).

Comment: Do I substitute workgroup or PC name for either of the terms somesystem & nameofresource?

Comment: OK, I have workgroup=FRENZGROUP and pc=HPLaptop and shared folder=HP_Data. So would I use these names?

Comment: You may use `smbclient //HPLaptop/HP_Data`, if it comes with any error, change `HPLaptop` with the current ip of the laptop (type `ipconfig` in the laptop) if still doesn't work, edit your question and add the results.

Comment: HPLaptop=NT_STATUS_UNSUCESSFUL & ip=NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new workgroup in your windows machines.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/join-or-create-a-workgroup

homegroups are the default and do not work for Linux. You can create a new user and password shareing all the resources you want. You should then see your windows machines and be able to log in as the new user.

Hope this helps
Larry Keenan

Comment: New workgroup. Now ubie sees the windows PC but when I click the PC in file manager I get "Unable to access location - Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out"?